# MS Access 2013 - Populate Fields Based on Check Box

Tags: checkbox, field, ms-access-2013, auto-populate

I have a form set up for data entry for new orders. When entering a new order a customer can be selected from a combo box. Shipping address, zip, state, etc. are in each customer record.

When a new order is made, the shipping destination may or may not be the the address attached to the customer.

I would like to add a check box to the form that when checked auto populates the shipping information fields to the customer's information. What would be the simplest way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use the On click event of the checkbox.

```
Private Sub Checkbox_Click()
    If Me.Checkbox = True Then
    Me.TextboxShipDest.Value = Me.TextboxShipAdress.Value
    Else
    Me.TextboxShipDest.Value = Null
    End If
End Sub
```